# openpyxl importar rangos y convertir en diccionario

Tags: python, diccionarios

En una hoja Excel tengo una tabla con dos columnas (Fecha y Valor). La fecha tiene el formato `dd/mm/yy`. Con el script que muestro a continuación importo los datos contenidos en el rango `A63:B80` de dicha hoja Excel.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import openpyxl
# Abrir el archivo y almacenarlo en doc
doc = openpyxl.load_workbook('cotizaciones.xlsx')
# hojas disponibles
print doc.get_sheet_names()
# seleccionamos hoja para trabajar
hoja = doc.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
hoja.title
# seleccionar un rango
seleccion = hoja['A63':'B80']
dicc_cotiz = {}
for filas in seleccion:
    for columnas in filas:
        print columnas.value
```

Con esta iteración consigo ver los datos importados, con este formato:

```
2017-06-15 00:00:00
44.14
```

Dos son los problemas que ahora me planteo:
a).- ¿cómo podría crear un diccionario con estos datos?.
b).- ¿cómo podría cambiar el formato de la fecha, para que fuera la clave en el diccionario con el formato `2017-06-15`, o mejor aún, `15/06/2017`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que las fechas (si están correctamente parseadas) son de tipo `date` solo tienes que usar [`date.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) para convertirlas a string con el formato deseado. Usando diccionarios por compresión sería algo así:

```
dicc_cotiz = {fecha.value.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'): valor.value
                  for fecha,  valor in seleccion}
```

A strftime se le pasa una cadena con el formato de salida deseado, en este caso dia/mes/año. Puedes modificarlo a tu gusto, en este [enlace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) tienes las directivas que se pueden usar para especificar dia, mes, año, hora, etc.

Si los diccionarios por compresión te confunden el código con un for normal sería:

```
dicc_cotiz = {}
for fecha, valor in seleccion:
    dicc_cotiz[fecha.value.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')] = valor.value
```

Dado que seleccionas dos columnas, tus filas son siempre una tupla de dos valores. En vez de usar índices que queda menos claro y es menos eficiente puedes simplemente desempaquetar la tupla en el `for` directamente, eso es lo que hacemos con `for fecha, valor in seleccion`.

La salida sería (ejemplo):

```
>>> dicc_cotiz
{'15/06/2017': 44, '16/06/2017': 45, '17/06/2017': 14}
```

Ten en cuenta que si tienes fechas repetidas solo se almacenará la última (no puede haber claves duplicadas en un diccionario).

Estoy presuponiendo que todas las celdas de fecha tienen valores date válidos, de no ser así deberás filtrar estas filas.

Comment: Problema resuelto y conceptos aclarados. Las opciones funcionan. Muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, @efueyo recuerda que puedes aceptar aquella respuesta que consideres más útil, esta es la forma que existe en SO de indicar que una respuesta resuelve tu problema de cara a otros usuarios del sitio en la misma situación. Para saber como mírate, [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/15089). Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Para que los valores leídos pueden transformarse en un diccionario sin problemas es necesario que cada fecha sea única, sino debes tener en cuenta que cada elemento del diccionario tendrá únicamente el último valor leído para la fecha. Es decir, con estas celdas:

```
15/06/2016  44,14
15/06/2016  50
```

El diccionario resultante sería `{"15/06/2016": 50}`

Adaptando un poco tu código, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
dicc_cotiz = {}
for fila in seleccion:
    fecha = (fila[0].value).strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    valor = fila[1].value
    dicc_cotiz[fecha] = valor
```

En primer lugar iteramos sobre la selección, esto nos retornaría un conjunto de filas y celdas, podemos acceder a estas últimas mediante un índice `fila[0]` correspondería a la celda de la primer columna de la fila leída.

Por otro lado, en la columna `A`, aparentemente por lo que dices, estás recibiendo un objeto [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime), por lo que simplemente usando el método [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) resuelves el tema del formato.

La actualización de los elementos del diccionario, lo hacemos de la forma habitual `diccionario[clave] = valor`.